# Multiple validation

Tags: forms

I have a problem regarding validation.
I have created a custom validation for email, but i want two additional validations for user name and last name. But only email field is getting validated.
My code:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id) {
if($form_id == 'email') {
   $form['#validate'][]='mymodule_form_validate_email';
}
if($form_id == 'name') {
   $form['#validate'][]='mymodule_form_validate_name';
}
}

function mymodule_form_validate_email($form, &$form_state) {

  $valid_email = $form_state['values']['email'];
  if (!valid_email_address($valid_email)) {
  form_set_error('email', 'Email adress, ' . $valid_email .' , is not valid. Please enter a valid email adress. Example: username@example.com');
  }
} 

function mymodule_form_validate_name($form, &$form_state) {

  $validate_name = $form_state['values']['name'];
  $name='user';//example
  if ($validate_name==$name) {
  form_set_error('Error');
  }
}
```

Now the problem is that 'email' validation works but the 'name' does not. I tried to copy the email validation to the validate_name function etc. but the same thing , nothing happens.

Comment: Are you sure that 'name' is the form_id? Have you verified (e.g., using dpm() or a debugger) that your validation function has been added to $form['#validate']?

Answer (score 1):

Attach the `#validate` property to the form submit button like this:

```
$form['submit']['#validate'][] = 'yourmodule_form_validate'
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this correct code, do you have two different - 2 forms one is "email" and another is "name". I think this code is not correct your $form_id can not be of this type. You can use [Get Form Id](http://drupal.org/project/get_form_id) module for this. Please correct your $form_id  first and then attach validation for every field or you can also call custom validate function and can validate both field together over there.

**Approach 1:** Validate all fields at one place in one function.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id) {
    if($form_id = 'Your form id') {
        $form['submit']['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_form_validation'
    }
}

function mymodule_form_validation($form, &$form_state) {
    $valid_email = $form_state['values']['email'];
    if (!valid_email_address($valid_email)) {
      form_set_error('email', 'Email adress, ' . $valid_email .' , is not valid. Please enter a valid email adress. Example: username@example.com');
    }

    $validate_name = $form_state['values']['name'];
    $name = 'user';//example
    if ($validate_name == $name) {
        form_set_error('Error');
    }
}
```

**Approach 2:** Validate individual field with individual function.
You can also validate individual element by attaching an #element_validate to the form element, with the element specific validation function. This function will be passed $form_state and $element. Using the same form example as above, define a validation function for the email and name element, rather than for the whole form.

```
'#element_validate' => array('mymodule_form_validate_email'),

'#element_validate' => array('mymodule_form_validate_name'),
```

Comment: Yes i have multiple forms like name,lastname, email etc... I wan to validate them separately.  Ill try the code later. Thanks